# How should I configure Ubuntu firewall?

Tags: 12.04, firewall

Just discovered Gufw, and I'd like to set it up.  But I haven't found any documentation telling me what I should/should not allow.  I'd like to be able to use it but the only documentation on the web seems to be instructions for how to create rules - little or no actual guidance as to WHAT those rules should be!  Could someone please guide me?

If it helps, I use my computer for the following:

Browsing the web (firefox)
Checking email (web based thru firefox)
Watching videos online (Youtube and streaming such as 4OD, BBC iPlayer)
Listening to radio online
Downloading music (haven't actually done it yet but will probably use Ubuntu One, or Amazon)
I also use digital camera and iPod but I assume they won't be affected by firewall?

I also have a Network printer connected wirelessly.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: IMHO ***Gufw** is a work in progress.* You probably need a good 'starter' script to setup the firewall. That will require an understanding of command-line manipulation of firewall rules. *Then, you can experiment with the GUI, to see what aspects can be maintained using that.*

Comment: I would look at `ufw` or Shorewall if you want a firewall - both are well-documented. Of course, I'd want to know why you think you need to run a firewall in the first place. Ubuntu, by default, does not open any ports unless a running service calls for them to be opened.